# My test cases are passing locally but getting unmarked on BrowserStack

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I am running my selenium test case on browserstack but its skipping the last 3 steps of the testcase and marking the status as UNMARKED. The browser stack suite report on Slack shows the Test cases as passed but when opened, it shows unmarked.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjHQE.png)

Its running fine on my local machine and passing as well without skipping any step.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC75x.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that BrowserStack is not aware if the test has passed or failed. Hence you would have to explicitly mark a session passed or failed.

In order to achieve the same, I am sharing a guide below:
https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/set-name-and-status-of-test